# Where can I download the latest version of Ubuntu for a PowerPC?

Tags: mac, powerpc

Where do we download the most current Ubuntu version for PowerPC Mac?

Answer (score 2):

The latest version of Ubuntu for PowerPCs is 13.10 Saucy Salamander.

Download links:

- 13.10

  - [Server ISO](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/13.10/release/ubuntu-13.10-server-powerpc.iso)
  - [Server Torrent](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/13.10/release/ubuntu-13.10-server-powerpc.iso.torrent)
- 13.04

  - [Desktop ISO](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/13.04/release/ubuntu-13.04-desktop-powerpc.iso)
  - [Desktop Torrent](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/13.04/release/ubuntu-13.04-desktop-powerpc.iso.torrent)
  - [Server ISO](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/13.04/release/ubuntu-13.04-server-powerpc.iso)
  - [Server Torrent](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/13.04/release/ubuntu-13.04-server-powerpc.iso.torrent)
- 12.10

  - [Desktop ISO (Lubuntu)](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/quantal/release/lubuntu-12.10-alternate-powerpc.iso.torrent)
  - [Desktop torrent (Lubuntu)](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/quantal/release/lubuntu-12.10-alternate-powerpc.iso.torrent)
  - [Alternate ISO (Lubuntu)](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/quantal/release/lubuntu-12.10-alternate-powerpc.iso)
  - [Alternate torrent](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/quantal/release/lubuntu-12.10-alternate-powerpc.iso.torrent)
  - [Server ISO](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/quantal/release/ubuntu-12.10-server-powerpc.iso)
  - [Server torrent](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/quantal/release/ubuntu-12.10-server-powerpc.iso.torrent)
- 12.04 LTS (Long term support)

  - [Desktop ISO](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/precise/release/ubuntu-12.04-desktop-powerpc.iso)
  - [Desktop torrent](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/precise/release/ubuntu-12.04-desktop-powerpc.iso.torrent)
  - [Alternate ISO](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/precise/release/ubuntu-12.04-alternate-powerpc.iso)
  - [Alternate torrent](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/precise/release/ubuntu-12.04-alternate-powerpc.iso.torrent)
  - [Desktop ISO (Lubuntu)](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/precise/release/lubuntu-12.04-desktop-powerpc.iso)
  - [Desktop torrent (Lubuntu)](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/precise/release/lubuntu-12.04-desktop-powerpc.iso.torrent)

For older versions and other distributions see [PowerPC Downloads - Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerPCDownloads).